# In Tkinter, how to define two checkboxes from one file in the function of a function in another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When i select `Tab2`, i would like to select the `Select all` checkbox which should automatically select the checkboxes `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`. The "Select all" Checkbox is located in the `x.py` file, so also the checkbox list `all_checkbox = [checkbox1, checkbox2]`. While the two checkboxes (checkbox1 and checkbox2) are found in the `page2.py` file. The code is reproducible.

[image]

**PROBLEM:** The problem is in the `all_checkbox = [checkbox1, checkbox2]` line of the `x.py` file, because i can't recover the two widgets from `page2.py`. I'm trying so many different ways, but I can't

**ERROR**: Of course, the error I get is that they are not defined:

```
NameError: name 'checkbox1' is not defined
NameError: name 'checkbox2' is not defined
```

**IMPORTANT:** I know I could solve the problem by moving `all_checkbox = [checkbox1, checkbox2]` to another place, but i need checkbox list is created inside file `x.py`, because the code in my question is just a short reproduced example of a larger project, so I need to organize it the way how I did it.

How can I define `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`, in all_checkbox = [checkbox1, checkbox2], of `x.py` file?

**ATTEMPT AT A SOLUTION:** What did I try to fix the problem? I tried using checkbox1, checkbox2 as parameter in `def myfunction`, like this `def myfunction(Verticalbar, checkbox1, checkbox2)`. So also in the `main.py` file in `if tab_text == "Tab2": myfunction(Verticalbar, checkbox1, checkbox2)`, but i get error:

```
NameError: name 'checkbox1' is not defined
NameError: name 'checkbox2' is not defined
```

I can't define them in `main.py` either

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Label, ttk
from page1 import Page1
from page2 import Page2
from x import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('475x325')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
page1 = Page1(nb)
page2 = Page2(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='Tab1', compound='left')
nb.add(page2, text='Tab2', compound='left')

Verticalbar = Frame(root, width=200, height=300, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
Verticalbar.place(x=1, y=40)

def on_tab_selection_changed(event):
    # First, get the selected tab id
    tab_id = nb.select()

    # Now we can get the tab text using the tab id
    tab_text = nb.tab(tab_id, "text")
    if tab_text == "Tab1":
        newlabel1 = Label(Verticalbar, text='TAB 1 EXAMPLE ', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
        newlabel1.place(x=2, y=3)

    if tab_text == "Tab2":
        myfunction(Verticalbar)
        
# Bind to a virtual event to detect when the tab selection changes
nb.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", on_tab_selection_changed)

root.mainloop()
```

**page2.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)


        #CHEXKBOX 1
        def test_checkbox1():
            print("Printed Checkbox 1")

        checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 1",
                                                            variable= self.checkbox1,
                                                            onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                                            highlightthickness=0, 
                                                            command= test_checkbox1)
        checkbox1.place(x=250, y=30)

        #CHEXKBOX 2
        def test_checkbox2():
            print("Printed Checkbox 2")

        checkbox2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 2",
                                                            variable= self.checkbox2,
                                                            onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                                            highlightthickness=0, 
                                                            command= test_checkbox2)
        checkbox2.place(x=250, y=60)
```

**x.py**

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk
import tkinter as tk


def myfunction(Verticalbar):
    newlabel2 = Label(Verticalbar, text='TAB 2 EXAMPLE', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
    newlabel2.place(x=2, y=3)


    def select_first_and_second():

        all_checkbox = [checkbox1, checkbox2]

        for cb in all_checkbox:
            cb.invoke()
            

    ### CHECKBOX SELECT ALL ###
    ckbx = tk.Checkbutton(Verticalbar, text="Select all",
                                    variable= ckbx_intvar,
                                    onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                    highlightthickness=0, command=select_first_and_second)
    ckbx.place(x=0, y=30)
```

This not needed, but I add them for completeness
​
**page1.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
```

Comment: @toyotaSupra Are you talking about checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton or all_checkbox = [self.checkbox1, self.checkbox2]?

Comment: @toyotaSupra So self.checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 1"..."?

Comment: Pass the checkboxes list to `myfunction()`.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Looking closer at my code, self.checkbox1 = tk.IntVar() and self.checkbox2 = tk.IntVar() are of no use to me. Small mistake of mine when I summarized the code of my project. I deleted these two, but the problem is another. Are you sure the problem is the duplicate? Why? To me it seems like an import and parameter problem, not duplicates. Explain yourself better

Comment: @acw1668 The list of checkboxes is contained in the nested function of myfunction. I tried to follow your suggestion, but the problem remains, because checkbox1 and checkbox2 of all_checkbox = [checkbox1, checkbox2] are not defined. Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the checkboxes to `myfuncion()`.

Below are the modified files:

##### page2.py

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)


        #CHEXKBOX 1
        def test_checkbox1():
            print("Printed Checkbox 1")

        self.checkbox1 = tk.IntVar()
        checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 1",
                                    variable= self.checkbox1,
                                    onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                    highlightthickness=0, 
                                    command= test_checkbox1)
        checkbox1.place(x=250, y=30)

        #CHEXKBOX 2
        def test_checkbox2():
            print("Printed Checkbox 2")

        self.checkbox2 = tk.IntVar()
        checkbox2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 2",
                                    variable= self.checkbox2,
                                    onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                    highlightthickness=0, 
                                    command= test_checkbox2)
        checkbox2.place(x=250, y=60)
        
        # create the checkbox list
        self.checkboxes = [checkbox1, checkbox2]
```

##### x.py

```py
from tkinter import Label, Tk
import tkinter as tk

# added all_checkbox argument
def myfunction(Verticalbar, all_checkbox):
    newlabel2 = Label(Verticalbar, text='TAB 2 EXAMPLE', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
    newlabel2.place(x=2, y=3)


    def select_first_and_second():

        #all_checkbox = [checkbox1, checkbox2]

        for cb in all_checkbox:
            cb.invoke()
            

    ### CHECKBOX SELECT ALL ###
    ckbx_intvar = tk.IntVar()
    ckbx = tk.Checkbutton(Verticalbar, text="Select all",
                            variable= ckbx_intvar,
                            onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                            highlightthickness=0, command=select_first_and_second)
    ckbx.place(x=0, y=30)
```

##### main.py

```py
...

def on_tab_selection_changed(event):
    # First, get the selected tab id
    tab_id = nb.select()

    # Now we can get the tab text using the tab id
    tab_text = nb.tab(tab_id, "text")
    if tab_text == "Tab1":
        newlabel1 = Label(Verticalbar, text='TAB 1 EXAMPLE ', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
        newlabel1.place(x=2, y=3)

    if tab_text == "Tab2":
        # pass the checkbox list inside page2
        myfunction(Verticalbar, page2.checkboxes)

...
```

Comment: In the x.py file, it says def myfunction(Verticalbar, all_checkbox) and then for cb in all_checkbox. Should I replace all_checkbox with checkboxes? Then def myfunction(Verticalbar, checkboxes) and then for cb in self.checkboxes

Comment: I'll read calmly this evening. Now I'm going to sleep. Thank you. P.S: maybe in your code there is a small careless error between all_checkbox and checkboxs. I haven't tried it yet, but I think it will work good. Thank you. See you later

Comment: @Nodigap The arguments of a function are just names which can be any meaningful names.

Comment: I know. In your code you forgot to replace all_checkbox with checkboxes (in the my function function and in the loop). I had to make some changes to your code and it works fine now. BUT THERE IS A PROBLEM: in the main question I asked to create the checkbox list directly in x.py, but instead you created it in page2.py. I would like to create the checkbox list inside x.py because this is just a small example of a larger project that I reduced the code to for Stackoverflow. (continue in next comment)

Comment: (continuation of comment above) I will have many checkboxes like Select All, Select only one, Select first two, etc. Each checkbox will have a list of 20-30 checkboxes. This will be a long code. So I would like to separate it from page2.py in order to organize it better, because page2.py will be used for something else and will have a lot of code for other different purposes. How can I use the checkbox list inside x.py? (preferably inside the select_first_and_second function, but it's also fine in the myfunction function or outside the functions. I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: My answer is based on your provided code.  Without more information on the source of *those checkboxes* mentioned in your comments, it is hard/impossible to provide solution.

Comment: They are simply two checkboxes (in page2.py) that print print("Printed Checkbox 1") and print("Printed Checkbox 2"). Then there is a third checkbox (Select All), in x.py that selects all. It's all very simple. I would like to create checkboxes = [checkbox1, checkbox2] inside x.py and not inside page2.py :) In your code you created it in page2.py and then used it in the x.py loop. I would like to create it in x.py and keep using it always in the loop in x.py. I also specified this in the "I know i could..." part. Could you help me as per the main question please? Thank you
​

Comment: It's been a few days, but maybe you haven't read the comment. Could you be so kind as to improve and edit your answer please? So I can vote for you and accept your solution. Thank you

Comment: @Nodigap I don't have another answer.

Comment: Okay. But your answer wasn't what I was looking for. I had written clearly in the question what I needed. Thanks anyway :/